# Wrap a (latent) sparse matrix as a numpy (dense) array (matrix) in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with a python library which only accepts `numpy.array` objects. However, my data is high-dimensional and very sparse and it is very inefficient loading it to memory in order the library gets the whole data. I was thinking in a memory efficient python object wrapping a sparse matrix. I found `scipy.sparse`, but the method of the library (obviously) rejects the data-type. I'd like that the sparse matrix object were latent (wrapped) behind a numpy object.

```
In [16]: x
Out[16]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
   with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [17]: print x
 (0, 0) 1.0
 (0, 2) 2.0
 (1, 2) 3.0
 (2, 0) 4.0
 (2, 1) 5.0
 (2, 2) 6.0
In [18]: y = wrapping_object(x)
Out[18]: 
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
In [19]: library.method(y)
Out[19]: 
True
```

I don't know if it is possible. Thank you for alternating or easier suggestions also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.

`x` is a sparse matrix.  `library.method` is the function that expects a dense (`numpy`) array.  And `wrapping_object` is the method/class that you are looking for, that will make `x` look like `y` without actually generating `y` (with the attendant memory consumption problems)?

`x.toarray()` (or `x.A` in short property notation) is the usual way of getting a dense array from sparse.  (`x.todense()` produces the `np.matrix` version).  So `fn = x.toarray` is a bound function that when executed will produce the dense array.  In a sense it is a wrapper.  But `library.method` won't use it that way, and probably won't accept it as an array.

We have to know more about how `library.method` uses `y` to know if there's a way around the issue.  Sometimes Python code checks the class of an input, but more often it just tries to use it in an expected way, and raises an error if it does not respond correctly.  It's the `if it quacks like a duck it's a duck` philosophy.

A sparse matrix behaves like an array in many ways, but not in every way. It has `shape`, `dtype`, responds to indexing, works with `x*3`, but not with `x+3`, etc.

The actual data for `x` is stored in 3 arrays, `x.data`, `x.indices`, `x.indptr`.  Other sparse formats use different attributes.

Comment: Thank you for reply @hpaulj, I actually assert your first line as exactly what I want: "`x` is a sparse matrix. `library.method()` is the function that expects a dense (`numpy`) array. And `wrapping_object` is the method/class that you are looking for, that will make `x` **look like** `y` **without actually generating** `y` (_with the attendant memory consumption problems_)". In my particular case `library.method()` is an interface to a method of a C++ wrapped library [here](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/1.0.0/classshogun_1_1CSparseFeatures.html); which I wouldn't like to manipulate.

Comment: At a first glance that looks like a sparse matrix library written in C++.  I assume one input method is to give it a dense matrix.  Is there another input style that accepts some sparse format?  Remember `csr_matrix` accepts several styles of input.

Comment: The problem is that other objects (e.g. a neural network) included in this library only accept `SpaseFeatures` objects. It is what does not allow the use of `csr_matrix` directly. Indeed `SpaseFeatures` object has its own method for efficiently loading hashed data from files (`load (CFile *loader)`), however this method is not available for the Python wrapper; only for C++ directly :(.

Comment: I was thinking of passing 3 arrays (vectors) to `SparseFeatures`, the `data`, `indices`, `indptr` attributes, or the `data`, `rows`, `cols` attributes of the `coo` format.  i.e. the coordinates and values of the nonzero elements of the matrix.

Comment: But `data`, `rows` and `cols` will be taken as feature vectors... Maybe this idea could be useful if I modify the code of `SparseFeatures` for reading the sciPy sparse format... Any way, I tested this idea and it does not work :(